# How to Show that (S V R) logically follows from the following knowledge base.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Not (Not Q) AND Z

• Not W

• (Not W And Q) -> Not P

• (W AND Z) -> S

• Q -> (S AND P)

• (P AND Q) -> R

Comment: There are two ways to derive a disjunction: Either derive one disjunct so to use *disjunction introduction*, or assume the negation aiming to derive a contradiction (a *reduction to absurdity* subproof).  Which have you tried?

Comment: A bunch of assumptions can never be knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The statement to be proved is $ S \vee R $ 
$ \neg (\neg Q) \land Z \implies Q \land Z \implies $ Q is tautology, Z is tautology 
$ Q \rightarrow S \land P \implies $ **S** is tautology, P is tautology 
Since we already know P and Q are tautologies, **R** is also a tautology from the last statement.

However, there is a contradiction between the third and fifth premise so this conclusion may not be useful.